# How to increase size of scattergeo plot in dash plot.ly?

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash

I've been learning dash and plot.ly to make some data viz with python. It's been great so far, but one nagging problem is that `scattergeo` plots don't utilize their space well.

I have the `scattergeo` plot sitting in a `width:100%` content div and it shares the total width 60/40 with another plot. But the space that the `scattergeo` uses is much less than the space allotted. Below is an image where the `scattergeo`'s div has a border around it showing how inefficiently it uses its space.

Is there any way to increase this plot type's space utilization within its `div` element?

[image: scatter geo space inefficiency]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, the solution I found was to use update_layout in this way:
`figure = offline.plot(go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout).update_layout(height=300, margin={"r":0,"t":25,"l":0,"b":0}), output_type='div', show_link=False)`